# how to count 2 times in one mongodb find?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

some documents like that

```
{"_id" : "00001",
 "member" : [ {'name':'Tom', 'code':'520'},{'name':'Dean', 'code':'523'},{'name':'Bob', 'code':'521'}],
 "class" : "2014"}

{"_id" : "00002",
 "member" : [ {'name':'Tom', 'code':'520'},{'name':'David', 'code':'524'}],
 "class" : "2015"}
```

I use

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$member"},
  {'$project':{'member.name':1}},
  {'$group':{'_id':'$member.name','count':{'$sum':1}}},
  {'$sort':{'count':-1}},
  {'$limit':1}
])
```

to get which name is most popular name,can i get another name total nums(sum another nums total not include popular name) in one search? how to modify this command?thanks.for example, 
i can get all information if don't use limit,
{ "_id" : "Tom", "count" : 2 }{ "_id" : "Dean", "count" : 1 }{ "_id" : "Bob", "count" : 1 }{ "_id" : "David", "count" : 1 },can i get Tom count2 and other total count3 in one search,or i have to count twice for other total num in first result.

Comment: can you explain bit more with example what do you want?

Comment: well you can use $skip to skip the first one in your pipeline to remove most popular name, however if you change $limit to 2, you will get both. I am sure I didn't get the question correctly though.

Comment: @Rahul Kumar thanks,i need get 2 nums ,first  most popular name nums, second other name total nums ,can i get both in one command?